# Gridview data not getting displayed based on combobox selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I am developing a restaurant application in which a new order will be placed. Itemtype will be in combobox. And based on the selection of combobox value, results should be displayed in DataGridView. For example, if I select "Biryani" Item in combobox, all the Biryani type items should be displayed in DataGridView.

Comment: Please add the code you have in the question.

Comment: Use AutoPostBack = True In your combo. So when the event index_change occur select from your database the results, or you can do it through ajax. But is MANDATORY to provide what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

As i can read that you are talking about DAtaGridView and ComboBox, you must be using Windows Forms. So what you ca do is call SelectedIndexChanged event of ComboBox, then you can bind the DataGridView. e.g

> ```
> private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
> {
>       ComboBox combo = sender as ComboBox;
>           if(combo.SelectedIndex >=0)
>           {
>               int itemId=Convert.ToInt32(combo.SelectedValue);
>               datagridview1.DataSource = somFunction(itemId);
>           }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, you could probably do this:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Windows.Forms;

  namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
     public partial class Form1 : Form {

        public class Selection {
           public enum eType { None, Indian, Chinese, Italian, British };
           public eType Type { get; private set; }
           public string Name { get; private set; }

           public Selection(eType xType, string xName) {
              Type = xType;
              Name = xName;
           } //

        } // class

        private List<Selection> _AllMeals = new List<Selection>();
        public Form1() {
           InitializeComponent();
           comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Selection.eType)).Cast<Selection.eType>();
           comboBox1.SelectedItem = Selection.eType.None;

           Selection s1 = new Selection(Selection.eType.Chinese, "tasty Wan Tan soup");
           Selection s2 = new Selection(Selection.eType.Chinese, "yummy Spring Rolls");
           Selection s3 = new Selection(Selection.eType.Indian, "extreme spicy");
           Selection s4 = new Selection(Selection.eType.Indian, "deadly spicy");
           Selection s5 = new Selection(Selection.eType.Italian, "great Tortellini");
           Selection s6 = new Selection(Selection.eType.Italian, "large Pizza");
           Selection s7 = new Selection(Selection.eType.British, "fatty Fish and Chips");

           _AllMeals.AddRange(new Selection[] { s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7 });
           dataGridView1.DataSource = _AllMeals;
        } //

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
           object o = comboBox1.SelectedItem;
           Selection.eType lFilter = (Selection.eType)o;

           var lOptions = (from x in _AllMeals
                           where x.Type == lFilter
                           select x).ToArray();

           dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
           dataGridView1.DataSource = lOptions;
           dataGridView1.Invalidate();
        } //

     } // class
  } // namespace
```

Visit my blog at www.ohta.de

Comment: This is a ASP.NET WebForms question related nand your answer for Windows DataGrid